# dropdown is populating empty list in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Laravel Version 6. PHP 7.4.

I simply wants to populate my dropdown values form database table. Initially, It was returning error "variable undefined" but when I enclosed my code into **if** condition, my error was gone but drop-down list is empty.

Please suggest where I' m stuck.

Route.php

```
Route::get('products/qrcodes/basic','niceActionController@getMake');
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NiceAction;
use App\NiceActionLogged;

public function getMake()
{
$records = DB::table('users')->get();
return view('products.qrcodes.basic', ['records' => $records]);
}
```

View

```
<form>
   <select  required>
     @if ((empty($records)))
        Whoops! Something went wrong
     @else
     @foreach ($records as $item)
     <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
     @endif
   </select>
</form>
```

I also tried **"dd($records);"** but nothing happens.

Comment: `use \Illuminate\Http\Request;` remove `/` like `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` it might be the issue.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir Thanks bro but "Khalid" has already fixed my issue. See my pasted  solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Make sure that your table have data. 
And then change your controller and view like this.

**Controller Code**

```
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use DB;
   use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use App\NiceAction;
   use App\NiceActionLogged;

   public function getMake() {
       $records = DB::table('users')->get()->toArray();
       return view('products.qrcodes.basic', compact('records'));
   }
```

**View Code:**

```
<form>
    <select required>
        @if(empty($records))
            Whoops! Something went wrong
        @else
            @foreach ($records as $key => $item)
                <option value="{{ $item['id'] }}">{{ $item['name'] }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </select>
</form>
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thanks and I just implemented your suggested code but no luck at all :(. 
It's a simple user table with 2 entries and I' m trying to get id and name, simple. 

Any other suggestion ?

Comment: Did you checked your database ?@Shaan

Comment: and @Shaan add use DB; in the controller file after namespace line, I just edited my controller file, check it

Comment: @shaan I mean does it have data ?

Comment: I just added line use DB; still empty list..  :(

Comment: @Shaan  bro run this command php artisan tinker and then run the query which you have given in the controller and tell me what you got

Comment: bro it's returning 2 records from table like id, name, email, phone etc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215163/discussion-between-khalid-khan-and-shaan).

Answer (score 1):

I'm happy to announce that @Khalid Khan has helped me to solved my issue. What he identified is I had defined two identical routes mistakenly. Upon pasting my latest route above previous one, my code worked.

Previous route:

```
    Route::get('products/qrcodes/{firstQR}
```

Latest route:

```
    Route::get('products/qrcodes/basic','niceActionController@getMake');
```